# when does Javascript Engine work?

Tags: javascript, web, browser, v8

I am studying about browser and I have a question.

the process of HTML I found out is,

1. Network Engine in Browser get a HTML file from Web Server.
2. HTML parser start to parse HTML file and make DOM.
3. Web Layout Engine start to render by using DOM

when the Html parser meet < script >< /script >, they call the Javascript engine immediately for interpreting code? Or
the parser collect them and then send the  part after making DOM?

If they call Javascript Engine immediately, what if there are code about editing DOM object before finishing to make DOM.

If I got a wrong, please tell me a correct

Comment: `<script>` tags are run as soon as they are encountered (the parser reads the file from top to bottom). Any HTML below the `<script>` will be "invisible" to any of the code that runs initially. This is why it's often times necessary to use the `onload` event in order to wait for the DOM to finish loading before most of the JavaScript runs.

Comment: Thanks you so much. I got it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct in both your assumption that it immediately begins interpreting code as well as your guess as to possible errors.

For the following example

```
<div id="test"></div>
<script>
  console.log(document.getElementById('test'));
</script>
```

You would see the div element logged in the console. However below since the javascript is before the div, you would see `null` logged instead.

```
<script>
  console.log(document.getElementById('test'));
</script>
<div id="test"></div>
```

This is why in modern web development people put their script tags at the bottom of the body.

```
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <!-- HTML CONTENT -->
    <div id="test"></div>
    <!-- script CONTENT -->
    <script>
      console.log(document.getElementById('test'));
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: nitpicking but `getElementById` returns `Element || null`, not `Element || undefined`

Comment: so how about external library??
I saw lots of case the script tag in head for loading external library such as angular js, Jquery and something like that.
is there no code about editing DOM in that libraries?
I hope I'm not bothering you.

Comment: Your not (:  and they either do not edit the DOM or they create their own via [document.body.append](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild) or expose a variable to be used later in the page. For example [lodash](https://lodash.com/) imported at the top of a file add the `_` object to the global scope. Feel free to ask whatever you want. @Kaiido when your right your right